# Replace all elements in Knockout.js observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, ko.observablearray

I have an `observableArray` in my view model. After creating the vm I wish to completely replace the data the `observableArray`. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
//Initial Setup
var vm = {};
vm.roles = ko.observableArray([]);
ko.applyBindings(vm); 


//....replace array later on....
vm.roles(["1", "2"]);
```

This seems to be working fine, but I was concerned if this was incorrect and might lead to memory leaks. Can anyone conform if this is the preferred way to update an existing `observableArray` assuming you wish to replace all its data?

I noticed `observableArray` does have a `removeAll()` method and wondered if that needed to be called to do this cleanly, or if I'm fine with what I'm doing?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The technique that you are using is the recommended approach for completely replacing the data in an `observableArray`.  An `observableArray` is actually just a normal `observable` with extra functions added for useful array operations that act on the underlying array and trigger notifications.

Comment: When you say "the recommended approach" my training from answering questions on http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/ kicks in. Would you happen to have supporting documentation/links for your statement? [  with respect, of course; you are Mr. Knockmeout himself (O;  ]

Answer (score -6):

I found that the recommended approach does not work in IE9 or lower.  Instead I had recreate the object,

```
vm.roles = ko.observableArray(["1","2"])
```

Comment: I wonder if that has changed with newer versions of Knockout... What version were you using?

Comment: If you replace the entire object, observers won't be notified, correct?