# Replace observableArray?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

I found this question to be similar as mine - [Replace all elements in Knockout.js observableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715936/replace-all-elements-in-knockout-js-observablearray)

I just have another question - if I replace all the elements of `observableArray` with new contents, will that reflect in the `UI` as well?

**Here's the scenario:** I have a `html` file which displays a `table` full of contents. Here is my `js` code snippet which fetches the data bound between `js` and `html`-

```
var table = ko.observableArray(); // {1,2,3,4,5} - UI shows 1,2,3,4,5 in the table
// now I replace all the contents
table = {6,3,8,9};
// **will the UI display the updated content, which is {6,7,8,9} in the table? Or will it still display {1,2,3,4,5}?**
```

Comment: In your question, the array is observable, its content not.  If you change an elment of the array, your UI don't get updated.  If you add/remove elements, then the UI is updated.  Here is more information:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: Yes. My intent is to remove all contents of the array and put new ones, and make sure the new ones reflect in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes since its an observable it will update the UI also.
See working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/fkxgk7rc/4/

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;  
  self.myList = ko.observableArray(data); 

  self.addToList = function (listData) {
    for (var i = listData.length; i-- > 0;)
       self.myList.push(listData[i]);
  }

  self.replaceList = function (listData) {
      self.myList(listData);
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 In the OP's example, the value of the var `table` is overwritten and would not update the UI.  In your answer and fiddle, the values are injected into the observable and the UI *is* updated.  This is an important distinction.  If someone simply reads the OP's example and your "Yes", they would come to the wrong conclusion about how this may be done.